# Trying to split a Keras input layer, processing both sub-tensors differently and connecting them latter into a LSTM layer

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

So, one input of my neural network in Keras is an array of 10 elements. The question is, the first 9 elements are numbers, while the last one is a matrix that will be concatenated. What I'm trying to do is:

- Receive the input
- Split the input, separating [0:8] and [9] entries
- Sending [9] entry into a series of convolution layers
- Ending it into a LSTM layer, which will receive the [0:8] entries directly and also the outputs of the convolution layers

I understand that will have to use an input layer:

```
shape = (10,)
input = Input(shape=shape , name='input', dtype='float32')
```

I also already have the convolution layers:

```
conv = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_kernels[0],
                     border_mode='valid', activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size),
                     kernel_initializer=initializer)(text_input)
conv = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=3)(conv)

conv1 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_kernels[1],
                      border_mode='valid', activation='relu',                                                                                                         kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv)
conv1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=3)(conv1)

conv2 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_kernels[2],
                      border_mode='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv1)

conv3 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_kernels[3],
                      border_mode='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv2)

conv4 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_kernels[4],
                      border_mode='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv3)

conv5 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_kernels[5],
                      border_mode='valid', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv4)
conv5 = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=3)(conv5)
conv5 = Flatten()(conv5)
conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(dense_outputs, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv5))
```

I also know that I will have to concatenate them latter and feed into a LSTM layer:

```
concat_lstm2 = Concatenate()([first, second])
Dropout(0.5)(LSTM(lstm_size, return_sequences=True, name='lstm')(concat_lstm2))
```

The question is how to split an entry to processes sub-entries in different layers, to latter concatenate them back into a LSTM layer.

Comment: Are the nine features and the matrix-shape features stored in different arrays? For example, you have an array of shape `(n_samples, 9)` and another array of shape `(n_samples, dim1, dim2)`, right?

Comment: @today It is a single array, having 9 elements that are numbers, and a 10th element which is a dim1xdim2 matrix. What I was trying to accomplish was inserting this array into a single input, and them separating the 10th element to be processed separated from the other 9 elements, and then concatenating these 9 elements with the result of the convolution in the 10th element.

Comment: Why don't you separate it from the beginning and feed it to the network with two separate input layers for each one?

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite of concatenate, and not finding it.  Aha.  Slicing.  This seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886992/slicing-a-tensor-with-keras