# Slicing a tensor with Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I have a 3D tensor. It is not an image, but for the sake of using the same conventions as Keras I will consider it an image, i.e. `height x width x channels`.

I have applied a 2D convolution to this tensor, and it is the input for a sequence of layers. However, I would like to keep the last channel separately, to concatenate it later on. Perhaps it is easier to see in code:

```
l = [64, 32, 16, 8]
inputs = Input(shape=(x,y,z))
we_are_here = Sequential([Conv2D(z, (x, y), padding='same') for _ in l])(inputs)
last_channel = SomethingSomething(we_are_here) # How do I do this?
long_path = Sequential(lots_of_layers)(we_are_here)
res = Concatenate([Flatten()(layer) for layer in [long_path, last_channel]]
outputs = Sequential([Dense(i) for i in l])(res)
```

I could not find a way to separate the last channel. There are several operations for slicing, splitting, cropping, etc. but none seems to help.

Comment: If you're familiar with list slicing in regular Python, array-like types support the same behavior, but generalized to additional dimensions. `arr[:, :, -1]` would get the last slice along the third dimension, and `arr[:, :, :-1]` would get all but that last slice.

Comment: I think this is not so much regular Python as numpy (and pandas), but in any case it works, or so it seems. Thanks a lot. Please feel free to upgrade your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with list slicing in regular Python, array-like types support the same behavior, but generalized to additional dimensions. `arr[:, :, -1]` would get the last slice along the third dimension, and `arr[:, :, :-1]` would get all but that last slice.

Note that where `arr.shape` is `(a, b, c)`, `arr[:, :, -1]` will return an array of shape `(a, b)`. If the dimensionality needs to be preserved, `arr[:, :, [-1]]` will return an array of shape `(a, b, 1)`. `arr[:, :, :-1]` will return an array of shape `(a, b, c - 1)`.